My page becomes unresponsive when I attach the .js to the .html in VS Code
The Chrome Page becomes unresponsive when I attach my JavaScript file to my HTML file and as soon I remove my .js file the page again start to run properly. I am having issue with live server not working while attached JavaScript file.Previously it was working properly but suddenly it stopped working following the same methodology using script tag.live server stopped working giving message chrome stopped responding

Are there any errors in your dev console? Could your script be running an infinite loop?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to clearly state what your situation is and the specific problem you are having. We rarely can answer questions without seeing your code, so always include the relevant code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.) right in your question. Try to keep your question titles short and clear.

I used 
Without seeing your code, it's difficult to give this a valuable answer. I can provide some tips though:

Have you tried to add console.log() calls in your code? It can be extremely useful to help find out if your code is running at all, or where the problem is occurring
Try a different .js file. It could be the issue is perhaps malformed HTML, or it could be your particular .js file
The previous might help with this: Try making sure the file structure is accessible (your files are all located in the right folders)

As I said in the beginning, it's difficult to help more than this without seeing your code or having a better description of your problem.

I cannot add i add image its saying i dont have points

I know the struggle. The exact reason I'm finding posts like yours to respond to is to build up my own reputation. StackOverflow is really tough about this stuff. I'd probably edit your original with the code pasted in it? I don't know what image you'd want to put here otherwise...
